# R: Faster alternative to generate unequal factor levels

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I have a large dataframe of over 2 million rows. Each row consists of a payment made by an individual and the month that this payment took place. different individuals are indexed by their `id`, and some individuals have more repayment months than others. Here is a sample of the data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L, 
1L,1L,1L,1L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L), snapshot_at = c("2012-01-31", 
"2012-02-29", "2012-03-31", "2012-04-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-30", 
"2012-07-31", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-30", "2012-10-31", "2012-11-30", 
"2012-12-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", "2012-01-31", "2012-02-29", 
"2012-03-31", "2012-04-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-30"),
category = c("C","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","E", 
"A","A","A","A","A","B")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"snapshot_at", "category"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I need to assign a 'monthonbooks' variables which refers to the number of months that have passed since the start of the payments. I then need to recast this into wide format so that each row refers to a individual and new columns refer to the 'monthonbooks' I have achieved this with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
df_wide <- df %>% arrange(id, snapshot_at) %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(monthonbooks = gl(nrow(df), 1, n(), labels = rep(1:nrow(df), ordered = TRUE))) %>%
  dcast(id ~ monthonbooks, value.var = 'category')
```

However this is incredibly slow to run. I has taken about 5 minutes to process 15000 rows and I have to do this with over 2 million rows. It seems that the particularly slow part is in generating the factor levels with unequal numbers of id (this part: `mutate(monthonbooks = gl(nrow(df), 1, n(), labels = rep(1:nrow(df), ordered = TRUE)))`.  Does anyone know of a faster alternative to generate the unequal factor levels? It would be particularly great if the solution was based in dplyr, or a solution that can be implemented within the dplyr pipeline.

Comment: This? `df %>% 
  arrange(id, snapshot_at) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n=1:n())`

Comment: @Jimbou WOW! that really seems to work! I would love to know the difference that makes this so much faster. Is it possible to get an explanation about why my approach was so slow?

Comment: The call to `gl()` seems totally unnecessary, figure out how to get vector recycling to do it. Also, can't you leave `monthonbooks` as an integer until the end; only convert it to factor immediately before needed? Like, remove the dcast from the pipe, do the rest of the pipe stages, store the temporary result, then do dcast on that?

Comment: And the data.table version is likely faster, given that dcast is making very regular predictable references to a large array.

Comment: @smci Thanks! It does seem that `gl()` was unnecesary. I think though that this was the root of the problem, rather than the `dcast` which is a fast operation, even when a factor is supplied to the formula.

Comment: Alrighty. I never even knew `gl()` existed until this question, and it's better wherever possible to avoid creating temporaries of size 2million * 10, especially when vector recycling can probably do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a tidyverse without reshape2 solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  arrange(id, snapshot_at) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(monthonbooks=1:n()) %>%
  select(-snapshot_at) %>% 
  spread(monthonbooks, category) 
# A tibble: 2 x 15
# Groups:   id [2]
     id `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`   `10`  `11`  `12` 
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 C     D     D     D     D     D     D     D     D     D     D     D    
2    10 A     A     A     A     A     B     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# ... with 2 more variables: `13` <chr>, `14` <chr>
```